# Scroll position jumps on Android GridView

Tags: java, android

I have a `GridView` which contains several items. By clicking an item a new detail view is created. Then by clicking back button user is returned to `GridView`. I want to preserve exact scroll position and I have accomplished that with following code:

Creating GridView

```
mArtistList = (GridView) artistsView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
mArtistAdapter = new ArtistAdapter(mContext);
mArtistList.setAdapter(mArtistAdapter);

// Adapter gets items asynchronously
mArtistAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged () {

        // setting first selection item
        mArtistList.setSelection(sActiveItem);

        /*
         *
         * PROBLEM HERE
         * Works ok, but when user touches the GridView
         * scroll position jumps to position where it
         * would be without this line.
         *
         */
        mArtistList.scrollBy(0, sActiveTop);

        super.onChanged();
    }
});
```

When user clicks an item on `GridView`

```
sActiveItem = mArtistList.getFirstVisiblePosition();

// vertical spacing (5dp to pixels)
sActiveTop = (int) (5.0f * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

View firstItem = mArtistList.getChildAt(0);

if (firstItem != null) {
    sActiveTop -= firstItem.getTop();
}
```

This works fine. Scroll position is exactly right after back button is pressed. The problem comes when user touches `GridView`. Scroll jumps to position where the first visible item is exactly at top of screen. How can I prevent this jump?

I don't speak english as my native language, so my explanation might be hard to understand. That's why I draw an image to indicate the problem:

[image]

Comment: Store your scroll position and reset it in onResume

Comment: The problem is not restoring scroll position. That already works fine. When user touches touches the screen, position jumps to incorrect position as shown in attached image.

Comment: sActiveTop = 0 there? getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0. Try sActiveTop = sActiveItem.getTop();

Comment: Thanks, but not working. `sActiveTop` is correctly calculated and the initial scroll offset is correct. When user touches the `GridView` things go wrong. I thing it has something to do with `GridView`s way of handling scrolling. It does not use values set with `scrollBy` or something like that...